# Reading appsetting-test.json file in asp.net core 5 test project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xunit, asp.net5

I have a test project with Asp.net core 5 and trying to read the appsetting values.

Created an appsetting.test.json file in the test project with below configuration

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://xxxxx.io/",
    "user": {
        "username": "xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com",
        "password": "xxxxxxx@1xx7"
    }
}
```

Created a helper class to read the json file

```
  public interface IAppSettingConfiguration
    {
        public static IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json")
                .Build();
            return config;
        }
    }
```

To read the baseurl I am using the below code

```
private IConfiguration _iAppSettingConfiguration;
private static string _readonlypageUrl;
public GivenAccount(PlaywrightFixture playwrightFixture)
        {
            _iAppSettingConfiguration = IAppSettingConfiguration.InitConfiguration();
            _readonlypageUrl = _iAppSettingConfiguration["baseUrl"];
            
        }
```

This is working fine I am able to get the value for base URL. How can use `IOption<>` to read whole object. In my case I want to read `user`

[image]

Not able to find the bind method from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
{
  /// <summary>Represents a set of key/value application configuration properties.</summary>
  public interface IConfiguration
  {
    /// <summary>Gets or sets a configuration value.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The configuration key.</param>
    /// <returns>The configuration value.</returns>
    string this[string key] { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets a configuration sub-section with the specified key.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the configuration section.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection" />.</returns>
    IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key);

    /// <summary>Gets the immediate descendant configuration sub-sections.</summary>
    /// <returns>The configuration sub-sections.</returns>
    IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren();

    /// <summary>Returns a <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken" /> that can be used to observe when this configuration is reloaded.</summary>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken" />.</returns>
    IChangeToken GetReloadToken();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want user details as an object, you can have a class created and bind it to `user` section from your configuration.

Something like,

```cs
private IConfiguration _iAppSettingConfiguration;
private static string _readonlypageUrl;
public GivenAccount(PlaywrightFixture playwrightFixture)
{
    _iAppSettingConfiguration = IAppSettingConfiguration.InitConfiguration();
    _readonlypageUrl = _iAppSettingConfiguration["baseUrl"];

    var _user = new UserDetail();
    _iAppSettingConfiguration.GetSection(UserDetail.User).Bind(_user);
    
}

public class UserDetail
{
    public const string User = "user";

    public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I don't have any Bind(_user) function, do I need to add some dependency ? I am using Asp.net core 5

Comment: You should be having it. It is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind

Comment: No I don't see any bind function, updated on the question with screenshot

Comment: you need to add the namespace 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Comment: I have added the IConfiguration code from microsoft extension in updated question

Comment: did you add the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder assembly?

Comment: It's actually an ExtensionMethod. So, it's not part of `IConfiguration`. It's part of  `ConfigurationBinder` static class inside `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace.

Comment: Add `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` and call `Bind` method. You should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine, was looking for this answer, Just I need to add <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" /> package

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

you can use the Services.Configure Method, when building your services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-options-with-a-delegate

Option 2:

However, if you need to do it manually, you need to get a sub-section

```
var username = IAppSettingConfiguration.GetSection("user").GetValue<string>("username");
var password = IAppSettingConfiguration.GetSection("user").GetValue<string>("password");
```

Comment: I am using the test project as a c# class library project. I don't have WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

Comment: to keep it simple, I added another solution without the ioption-pattern...

Answer (score 0):

Usual, if you want to get some field from your appsettings.json, you may to use Configuration methods that in WebApplicationBuilder at Startup.cs (at Program.cs in .NET 6)

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "bar": "someValue"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

For example, in case with appsettings.json file like that, we may get "bar" value by doing this (.NET 6 example)

```
var Foo = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Foo");
var Bar = Foo.GetSection("bar");
```

Or how it was before .NET 6.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
}
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var Foo = Configuration.GetSection("Foo")
    var Bar = Foo.GetSection("Bar")
}
```

I think this is the direction in which you need to think, good luck!

Comment: I don't have any startup class, since I am using test project as c# library project

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to me, that is the asp.net project.
So, there is no difference, you need to use IConfiguration to work with appsettings.
And about the part of question that was edited hour ago: you can't get user as object from json, but you can get params of user as sections, and create object as class instance with fields taken from those sections, for example.
Sorry if something is wrong, for my english.